# How can I get access to the files root directory without giving full path name in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a Windows application in Visual Studio 2008 with SQL Server CE as database. `D:/My Project/Library` is the root directory for my project's source code.

I have some files which I want to access within the forms of my project. They are stored in `D:/My Project/Library/New Resources`. To access those files I can't use the full path name because I keep changing the location of my project's source code. I need something like wherever the source directory may be the files must be accessed from there only.

Ex:

`Public Sub setconnection()
con = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=H:\Library\Library\Library1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
cmd.Connection = con
con.Open()
End Sub`

I want to use relative path name for Library1.mdf file without using **H:\Library\Library** path name.

Comment: The problem is that when deployed, your app may end up in `C:\Program Files...` in which case, your app likely wont have permission to sub folders there.  `ApplicationData` and `ProgramData` are a better choice depending on what these are.

Comment: From what you explained, I believe you want to get familiar with two most basic file system concepts, "current directory" and "relative path."

Comment: You are right GSerg. I need to use the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, though you may need to tack on some additional info.  A web project using this, for example, may need to append "/bin" to the end of the result to get the actual location of the DLLs.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```